# Are arrows in Coq aliases of universal quantifications?

Tags: coq

I'm reading [chapter 4 of the reference manual of Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual006.html). According to the typing rules described by the reference, the type of term `fun x: nat => x` is `forall x: nat, nat`.

```
Assume that E is [nat: Set].

              ...                                 ...
------------------------------ Prod-Set  ------------------- Var
E[] ⊢ forall x: nat, nat : Set           E[x: nat] ⊢ x : nat
------------------------------------------------------------ Lam
        E[] ⊢ fun x: nat => x : forall x: nat, nat
```

However, when I `Check` this term by Coq, it is typed `nat -> nat`.

```
Welcome to Coq 8.5pl2 (July 2016)

Coq < Check fun x: nat => x.
fun x : nat => x
     : nat -> nat
```

Are these two types same ones? If so, do arrows have hidden names of bound variables?

Comment: Try `Unset Printing Notations.` before checking the type of your term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual type of `fun x: nat => x` is `nat -> nat` because their is no type dependency. The arrow is syntax sugar for `forall _:nat, nat`: the type of the body does not depend on the value of `x`, only the body itself is using `x`. An example of type dependency would be `vector`.

`vector A n` is the type of list of length `n` containing elements of type `A`. Let's consider the `concat` function which concatenate two vectors:

```
concat : forall n m: nat, vector n A -> vector m A -> vector (n + m) A
```

It takes as input two integers, `n` and `m`, two vectors of respective size `n` and `m` and concatenate them. This time, the *type* of `concat` depends on the value of `n` and `m` so you have to name them and use the `forall` instead of the `->`. If you try to write `nat -> nat -> vector n A -> ...`, the variable `n` won't be correctly bounded.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said arrow is indeed a notation. See [theories/Init/Logic.v#L13](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/1449af76331fbe4ab5807682db3ee4023f607418/theories/Init/Logic.v#L13) in the Coq sources:

```
Notation "A -> B" := (forall (_ : A), B) : type_scope.
```

This file is loaded by the Prelude, you can avoid it with with `-noinit`.